# Run batch "not as administrator"

Tags: batch-file

My main batch runs several small batch files as administrator. 
Now i need it to run as current user as the exe Il start says "dont run as admin"

I have tried in mybatch1.bat `runas /profile /user:%USERNAME% start /wait /min mybatch2.exe`

This just gives me a list of "runas"available commands

Answer (score 0):

Read *entire* `runas /?`; an excerption follows:

```
RUNAS USAGE:

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ] /user:<UserName> program

...

   program         command line for EXE.  See below for examples

Examples:
> runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
> runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
> runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""

NOTE:  Enter user's password only when prompted.
```

- read examples above for multi-word `program` usage .
- note that `program` should be a *command line for EXE* but `START` is an internal command.

Hence, `runas /profile /user:%USERNAME% "start \"\" /wait /min notepad.exe"` leads to following error (FYI, the system cannot find the file `start`):

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - start "" /wait /min notepad.exe
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

We could try `runas /profile /user:%USERNAME% "cmd /C start \"\" /wait /min notepad.exe"`. This command will launch `notepad` but following batch script
- **will not wait** for terminating `notepad`
- and displays the `EOF: 32197368.bat` message
- while `cmd /c` waits for terminating `notepad`:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
runas /profile /user:%USERNAME% "cmd /C start \"\" /wait /min notepad.exe"
echo EOF: %~nx0
```